# Locking of records

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a application where many employees may login to the system to solve customer complaints. If one employee clicks "Start" button for the complain, the record should be freezed. By freezed I mean it should not appear on other employees screen (when the screen updates on their machine using Ajax). Further it shouldn't appear only for a certain amount of time duration. If the employee doesn't response to the complain within few minutes it should again appear in the queue of complaints.

How do I manage this time duration? I have one approach where one the user clicks on "Start", I could store that item in Cache object and it's only valid until it's expiry comes. Then when other employee's screen refreshes I only show those items that are not attended and not present in Cache. If it is present in Cache it means it is being attended by someone. Am I going on the right track? Or is there any better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is have a 'lock' column in the database, and have that column be a DateTime column.

When a user clicks 'Start', note the time in that column.

When retrieving records for display, filter out any which have a non-null value in the lock column, or who's value in the lock column is from at least x minutes ago (which you can calculate using math on the GetDate() function).

Comment: Nice. I liked the solution. Most elegant one I've read without falling into unnecessary timers etc.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to have a column called 'RecordStatus' or something like that, which you can set to a special value to indicate it is still being created or modified.

This forces you to modify all your queries to specifically exclude records that have that status, but in the long term it works better and is more reliable than any type of database or application-level logical locks.

Comment: And what if the user that loads the record doesn't release it? How do you notify the database to auto-release the record on an asp.net  app, considering the fact that Session_End is not guaranteed to fire? I think your approach is on the right track but there's way more to do...

Comment: Yeah, that's always a problem. We have a batch job that runs daily, looks at records that were left in 'draft' mode and nukes them.

Comment: Your response inspired me to answer as well.  A nice solution for a time-based expiration of a lock is having the lock column be a DateTime (allow nulls) instead of a bool - you can then retrieve based on null lock or lock that was set x minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

We've solved this at my company in two situations, independently, using some variation on a "record lock" DB record. In one system the locking record is created when the record enters the "queue" as a new item; in the other, the locking record is created when a user picks up a record out of the queue.

Either way you slice it, as of when a user's copy of your software opens a queue record for work, a locking record should be in the DB with some uniquely identifying information about your user written to it. It should be unique to the record being locked, and maybe the lock level (meaning two locks of the same level cannot exist on the same record), and identifies the user who opened the record as "owning" it for the purposes of making changes. This locking record should persist as long as the user has the record open in his software.

The ability to "break" locks can be achieved by simply reassigning the lock to another user, coupled with regular polling of the locking object by the original locking user's software; if, at any time, the user no longer is the owner, the lock has been "broken" and the user has the option to reacquire the lock (breaking the other user's new lock) or simply move on.

Now, should the user's software crash, they will still own a lock on the record. It may also happen that the operation to remove the lock fails (this can happen in situations where the real data is in another DB and you cannot enforce a universal transaction). In such a case, you will need some mechanism to remove "orphaned" locks, or force the user to remove them. If the items being locked are time-sensitive, you will need to design multiple redundant levels of lock removal (perhaps a timed job that, once a minute, will break any lock older than X minutes or which is known to be "orphaned" because that user isn't logged in anymore).